# Prime Generation using Sieve of Eratosthenes with better performance

Tags: java, performance, primes

To Generate Prime upto N i was using this code .

```
private static void primePrint(int n) {
        int sum=0;
        int maxFactor= (int)Math.sqrt(n);
        boolean[] isPrime=new boolean[n + 1];
        int len=isPrime.length;
        Arrays.fill(isPrime,true);
        isPrime[0]=false;
        isPrime[1]=false;
        for(int i=0;i<=maxFactor;i++){
            if(isPrime[i]){
                for(int j=i+i;j<len;j+=i){
                    isPrime[j]=false;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
            if(isPrime[i]){
                System.out.println(i)
            }
        }

    }
```

But recently someone suggested me to half my maxfactor and use this loop because it increases the efficiency. but i'm not able to get this how it's been operating .

```
maxFactor = maxFactor/2 - 1;
    boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[n/2+1];
    for(int i = 0; i < maxFactor; ++i) {
        if (!isPrime[i]) {

            for(int j = 2*i*(i+3)+3, p = 2*i+3; j < n/2; j += p) {
                isPrime[j] = true;
            }
```

If someone can Throw light on this it would be of great help.

Edit: A working code that generated the nthPrime using this

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(nthPrime(25));
    }

    public static int nthPrime(int n) {
    if (n < 2) return 2;
    if (n == 2) return 3;
    int limit, root, count = 1;
    limit = (int)(n*(Math.log(n) + Math.log(Math.log(n)))) + 3;
    root = (int)Math.sqrt(limit) + 1;
    limit = (limit-1)/2;
    root = root/2 - 1;
    boolean[] sieve = new boolean[limit];
    for(int i = 0; i < root; ++i) {
        if (!sieve[i]) {
            ++count;
            for(int j = 2*i*(i+3)+3, p = 2*i+3; j < limit; j += p) {
                sieve[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    int p;
    for(p = root; count < n; ++p) {
        if (!sieve[p]) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return 2*p+1;
}
}
```

[IDEONE LINK](https://ideone.com/neORk0)

Comment: Are you looking for particular types of primes?

Comment: i'm not able to get how by reducing the number of check even half of the root and then checking till n/2 only it generating all the primes upto n. and what `j = 2*i*(i+3)+3, p = 2*i+3` is doing actually.

Comment: This is a standard optimization of the Sieve of Eratosthenes; it sieves only on odd numbers, since all even numbers except 2 are composite. See an explanation and derivation of the formula for _j_ at [my blog](https://programmingpraxis.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/primenumbers.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

> But recently someone suggested me to half my maxfactor and use this loop because it increases the efficiency.

I suspect that that "someone" is just wrong.  (Maybe they were teasing you ...)

The reasoning behind maxFactor == sqrt(N) is that:

- the sieve is *remove* numbers that are not prime
- if X is a non-prime, then it must have at least two prime factors.
- if X is less then N, then at least one of its prime factors must be less than or equal to sqrt(N)

However, if you make maxFactor smaller than sqrt(N), then you are likely to not remove one or more non-primes.  In other words you make a hole in the sieve.

---

And the inner loop in your modified version makes no sense to me ... as an implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

---

In fact, based on the code at the link you provided, I think that this is the [Sieve of Sundaram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram) (not the the Sieve of Eratosthenes as you labelled it.)  I would also note that the code at that link is solving a different problem: find the N-th prime (not all primes less or equal to N).

Anyway, my answer stands, as an answer to your question about implementing Sieve of Eratosthenes.

(And if you want a solution to Sieve of Sundaram ... you already have it.)

Comment: Well, if you look at his code, he is solving a different problem.  He is finding the N'th prime, not all primes less than N.

Comment: but he is calculating the required seive  and then marking what not as prime as true ? so can we not extend this to generate primes till N ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make this work for generating primes. To prove your friend didn't find a great new method to generate primes I submit:
    j = 2*i*(i+3)+3
Is what assigns primes but by the time you get to i=1 then j=11 and we have yet to assign 5 as a prime. Since I see no way for the algorithm to go back, we've missed a prime.

Also isPrime is initialized to size n/2+1 so we don't even have the space to collect the data we are looking for.